# Python syntax error when I use terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal

```
>>>k = 0;
>>>for k < 100:
       File "<stdin>", line 1
   for k < 100:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is that syntax error?

Comment: That's a syntax error. It seems that you've mistaken `for` with `while`.

Comment: That's not proper syntax for a `for` loop. Nothing to do with the terminal

Comment: Sorry.Found the mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using wrong syntax, use

```
while k < 100:
```